# MODx Revo empty variable condition doesn't return variables

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I use my own `get` snippet to get parameters from $_GET[]:

```
if ($set) {
    $modx->setPlaceholder($param, $_GET[$param]);
} else {
    return $_GET[$param]; }
```

When I use `[[!get? &param='mode' &set='1']]` to set `[[+mode]]` variable next sample is working for non empty `&mode` parameter:

```
[[+mode:eq=``:then=`[[*content]]`]]
```

But works for:

```
[[+mode:eq=``:then=`something else`]]
```

Any ideas how it is possible and how to avoid this?

Comment: Of course I use `[[!get:eq='':then=[[*content:ellipsis='240':notags]]'? &param='mode']]` now.
Bnd should I use `[[!get]]` or `[[get]]` for the next lines?

Answer (score 0):

The $set variable is now '1', could you try to typecast the $set with (bool) so '1' turns into TRUE?

You could also check the $param if it is empty inside the snippet and assign a value to it so you can check it without checking for empty value.

Comment: When `$set='1'` [[+mode]] get its value.

Comment: I can do check inside the snippet but what value should I assign? What if I have to leave assign `undef` just in case the value is empty and apply :default output filter?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand exactly what you were asking, but in MODX snippet syntax you should take care to always use backticks (`) instead of apostrophes (').

Also in this situation where the output depends on a parameter passed by $_GET, you should ensure your snippet is always called uncached, and possibly your placeholder too:

```
[[!get? &param=`mode` &set=`1`]]

[[!+mode:eq=``:then=`[[*content]]`]]
```

Comment: In call I used backticks (`) instead of apostrophes ('). Have to replace it for stackoverflow.